# How do I add a jar-file to Ant for a NetBeans Java Web App project so that it gets build on Jenkins?

Tags: java, netbeans, ant, jenkins, restful-architecture

As I pointed out in [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25061162/how-do-i-fix-this-ant-cannot-find-file-when-trying-to-build-a-java-web-applic), I am trying to set up an automatic build system with Jenkins CI for a NetBeans multitiered web application project.

My Ant targets are *clean* and *debug*. Clean works, but debug fails when trying to compile the project.

In the output of my Jenkins build I see the following command:

*[PGB Webapp] $ cmd.exe /C '""C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\tools\hudson.tasks.Ant_AntInstallation\Apache_Ant\bin\ant.bat" "-Dlibs.MySQLDriver.classpath=C:/Program Files (x86)/MySQL/MySQL Connector J/mysql-connector-java-5.1.31-bin.jar" "-Dlibs.CopyLibs.classpath=C:/Program Files/NetBeans 8.0/java/ant/extra/org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar" "-Dj2ee.server.home=C:/Program Files/wildfly-8.1.0.Final" clean debug && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%"'*

And this is the last part of my output: (the part that seems most important to me)

```
library-inclusion-in-manifest:

-do-compile:
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\PGB Webapp\pgb-war\build\empty
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\PGB Webapp\pgb-war\build\generated-sources\ap-source-output
    [javac] Compiling 2 source files to C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\PGB Webapp\pgb-war\build\web\WEB-INF\classes
    [javac] C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\PGB Webapp\pgb-war\src\java\com\edw\config\ApplicationConfig.java:6: error: package javax.ws.rs.core does not exist
    [javac] import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
    [javac]                        ^
    [javac] C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\PGB Webapp\pgb-war\src\java\com\edw\config\ApplicationConfig.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {
    [javac]                                        ^
    [javac]   symbol: class Application
    [javac] C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\PGB Webapp\pgb-war\src\java\com\edw\rest\EmployeeResource.java:12: error: package javax.ws.rs does not exist
    [javac] import javax.ws.rs.GET;
    [javac]                   ^
    [javac] C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\PGB Webapp\pgb-war\src\java\com\edw\rest\EmployeeResource.java:13: error: package javax.ws.rs does not exist
    [javac] import javax.ws.rs.Path;
    [javac]                   ^
    [javac] C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\PGB Webapp\pgb-war\src\java\com\edw\rest\EmployeeResource.java:14: error: package javax.ws.rs does not exist
    [javac] import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
    [javac]                   ^
    [javac] C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\PGB Webapp\pgb-war\src\java\com\edw\rest\EmployeeResource.java:15: error: package javax.ws.rs does not exist
    [javac] import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
    [javac]                   ^
    [javac] C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\PGB Webapp\pgb-war\src\java\com\edw\rest\EmployeeResource.java:16: error: package javax.ws.rs does not exist
    [javac] import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
    [javac]                   ^
    [javac] C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\PGB Webapp\pgb-war\src\java\com\edw\rest\EmployeeResource.java:17: error: package javax.ws.rs.core does not exist
    [javac] import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
    [javac]                        ^
    [javac] C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\PGB Webapp\pgb-war\src\java\com\edw\rest\EmployeeResource.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] @Path("/employees")
    [javac]  ^
    [javac]   symbol: class Path
    [javac] C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\PGB Webapp\pgb-war\src\java\com\edw\rest\EmployeeResource.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public List<Employee> find(@QueryParam("name") String name) {
    [javac]                                 ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class QueryParam
    [javac]   location: class EmployeeResource
    [javac] C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\PGB Webapp\pgb-war\src\java\com\edw\rest\EmployeeResource.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]         @GET
    [javac]          ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class GET
    [javac]   location: class EmployeeResource
    [javac] C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\PGB Webapp\pgb-war\src\java\com\edw\rest\EmployeeResource.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
    [javac]      ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class Produces
    [javac]   location: class EmployeeResource
    [javac] C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\PGB Webapp\pgb-war\src\java\com\edw\rest\EmployeeResource.java:38: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public Employee findById(@PathParam("id") String id) {
    [javac]                               ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class PathParam
    [javac]   location: class EmployeeResource
    [javac] C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\PGB Webapp\pgb-war\src\java\com\edw\rest\EmployeeResource.java:36: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     @GET @Path("{id}")
    [javac]      ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class GET
    [javac]   location: class EmployeeResource
    [javac] C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\PGB Webapp\pgb-war\src\java\com\edw\rest\EmployeeResource.java:36: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     @GET @Path("{id}")
    [javac]           ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class Path
    [javac]   location: class EmployeeResource
    [javac] C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\PGB Webapp\pgb-war\src\java\com\edw\rest\EmployeeResource.java:37: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
    [javac]      ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class Produces
    [javac]   location: class EmployeeResource
    [javac] C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\PGB Webapp\pgb-war\src\java\com\edw\rest\EmployeeResource.java:44: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public List<Employee> findByManager(@PathParam("id") String managerId) {
    [javac]                                          ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class PathParam
    [javac]   location: class EmployeeResource
    [javac] C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\PGB Webapp\pgb-war\src\java\com\edw\rest\EmployeeResource.java:42: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     @GET @Path("{id}/reports")
    [javac]      ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class GET
    [javac]   location: class EmployeeResource
    [javac] C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\PGB Webapp\pgb-war\src\java\com\edw\rest\EmployeeResource.java:42: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     @GET @Path("{id}/reports")
    [javac]           ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class Path
    [javac]   location: class EmployeeResource
    [javac] C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\PGB Webapp\pgb-war\src\java\com\edw\rest\EmployeeResource.java:43: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
    [javac]      ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class Produces
    [javac]   location: class EmployeeResource
    [javac] C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\PGB Webapp\pgb-war\src\java\com\edw\config\ApplicationConfig.java:17: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    [javac]     @Override
    [javac]     ^
    [javac] C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\PGB Webapp\pgb-war\src\java\com\edw\config\ApplicationConfig.java:22: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    [javac]     @Override
    [javac]     ^
    [javac] 22 errors

BUILD FAILED
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\PGB Webapp\nbproject\build-impl.xml:208: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\PGB Webapp\pgb-war\nbproject\build-impl.xml:881: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\PGB Webapp\pgb-war\nbproject\build-impl.xml:297: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 1 second
Build step 'Start Ant' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Well, the important thing here is that the Java compiler is not able to locate the RESTful Web Services library. I found the jar I need at *C:/Program Files/wildfly-8.1.0.Final/modules/system/layers/base/javax/ws/rs/api/main/jaxrs-api-3.0.8.Final.jar*.

I have no experience with the Ant buildtool, so I have searched and found a lot about it, but I cannot seem to figure out how to get this library added so that the project gets properly build on Jenkins.

Currently my build.xml file looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="pgb" default="default" basedir="." xmlns:ear="http://www.netbeans.org/ns/j2ee-earproject/2">
    <description>Builds, tests, and runs the project pgb.</description>
    <import file="nbproject/build-impl.xml"/>

    <taskdef resource="net/jtools/classloadertask/antlib.xml">
      <classpath>
        <fileset dir="${basedir}/lib" includes="ant-classloader*.jar"/>
      </classpath>
    </taskdef>

    <!--Add jar to the classpath-->
    <classloader loader="system">
      <classpath>
        <fileset dir="${basedir}/lib" includes="jboss-modules.jar"/>
        <fileset dir="${basedir}/lib" includes="jaxrs-api-3.0.8.Final.jar"/>
      </classpath>
    </classloader>
</project>
```

The file build-impl.xml (which is imported) is generated by NetBeans (as you may probably know already) and is too big to display here, besides I could not change anything there because the system might automatically change that file itself.

Anyway, as you can see I've tried to use an Ant Classloader I found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5116470/2541501
But no luck there.. I even added the required jar-file to the lib directory of the project.

So, my question is: how do I change my Ant buildscript so that the Java compiler does not complain about missing packages (i.e. missing jar files)?

I am also worried that if I add any targets to my build.xml file that it might conflict with anything that is declared in the generated build-impl.xml file. Anyone also know anything about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay my colleague found out that **we simply needed to copy the private properties of the NetBeans project into the Properties field of the Ant Invoke** of the Jenkins job of our project.

So, our NetBeans project has a directory called *private* in the *nbproject*-directory. In this *private* directory there is a file called *private.properties*. We took the properties from this file and copied it into the Properties field of the Ant Invoke. Now our Properties field looks as follows:

```
libs.CopyLibs.classpath=C:/Program Files/NetBeans 8.0/java/ant/extra/org-netbeans-modules-java-j2seproject-copylibstask.jar
libs.MySQLDriver.classpath=C:/Program Files (x86)/MySQL/MySQL Connector J/mysql-connector-java-5.1.31-bin.jar

j2ee.platform.is.jsr109=true
j2ee.server.domain=C:/Wildfly/standalone
j2ee.server.home=C:/Wildfly
j2ee.server.instance=wildfly-deployer:localhost:8080#standalone&C:\\Wildfly
```

Now we can perform all Ant commands without a problem. We are also able to deploy the web application that is build through Jenkins.

If anyone is wondering, the RESTful Web Services can be found in WildFly. So we don't need to include the jar of the RESTful Web Services directly, all we need is to set the properties for the WildFly server right.

In retrospect, I would say that it is not that hard at all to set-up a continuous integration system with automatic builds for a NetBeans project. Now, next step is to also include automated testing for the project.