# including -lib command line argument in build.xml?

Tags: java, ssh, ant, scp

How to include `jsch-0.1.53.jar` file in build.xml (to execute ant sshexec and scp) other than passing as command line argument - lib `jsch-0.1.53.jar`?

Comment: [Have you look here?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104507/how-can-i-specify-the-path-of-a-jar-in-an-ant-buildfile) <br/>
Looks like author have the same intends as you.

Comment: Another duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13468153/loading-jsch-library-from-local-lib-directory-in-ant-build-xml/13480683#13480683

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way, if you have the possibility, is copy it into your ant lib installation